# Duplicate content for desktop and mobile

Tags: seo, html, duplicate-content, css

front end dev here.

Quite often the design team I work with produces desktop and mobile designs which are quite difficult to create responsively. While it can be done, I feel like I am using an excessive amount of my time on making this work.

I'm just wondering if modern search engines would score us down if I were to, for example have two footers with same content with a different html structure and only display one for mobile and one for desktop

Comment: read more Mobile site and mobile-first indexing best practices https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/mobile/mobile-sites-mobile-first-indexing?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem as long as

- They have the same URL and the total content is not vastly different
- Or different URLs with a canonical tag.

Just in case, you should use or backend to detect if its a mobile or desktop and serve the appropriate footer, rather than having both of them in the HTML.

Comment: I was thinking of having the same page with the same content twice, duplicated but hiding one and displaying the other depending on the device